# Applied Topology/Topological Data Analysis conferences and journals

Tags: applied-mathematics

Can someone point out links to Applied Topology/Topological Data Analysis conferences and journals?

Thank you!

Comment: You might be interested in the resources of the Applied Algebraic Topology Research Network: https://topology.ima.umn.edu

Comment: Yup, I am already registered in AATN and regularly attend the seminars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATMCS (Algebraic Topology: Methods, Computation, and Science), Oxford University, Oxford, UK, June 20–24, 2022. (I just googled.)

International Conference on Computational Topology and Data Analysis ICCTDA on September 20-21, 2021 in Toronto, Canada

International Conference on Computational Topology and Topological Data Analysis ICCTTDA on December 09-10, 2021 in London, United Kingdom

International Conference on Computational Topology and Data Analysis ICCTDA on December 16-17, 2021 in Barcelona, Spain

ICCTTDA001 2022: 16. International Conference on Computational Topology and Topological Data Analysis
May 17-18, 2022 in Paris, France